# Elasticsearch retrieving a list of ids

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a list of ids and I want to retrieve them on elasticsearch. The list is about `400 000` elements what is the best way to retrieve the document associated to those ids? I tried:

```
es_response = ES.mget(index='users', doc_type='inactive', body={'ids': user_ids})
```

But I get a timeout. Is the multiple GET the best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely should consider splitting your list of ids into a smaller groups and request them separately. It will also simplify serialization/deserialization of requests/responses